# You pay a payment and you receive a what?

Tags: antonyms

I am confused as to what word can you to mean the opposite of a payment (some cash flow that you receive).

Is it "receipt"?

Comment: You **receive a payment** that someone else **makes**.The word is payment for both, but you either make it or receive it depending on which end of the deal you're on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You receive a payment that someone else makes.The word is payment for both, but you either make it or receive it depending on which end of the deal you're on – @MorganFR